Launch trim version of Eclipse
I want to host Eclipse Help on a server. I found a discussion on the Eclipse forum about creating help on a server. (I am very grateful to the person on the forum who described everything in detail)
This method required trimming Eclipse, which I successfully did.
Link to the discussion: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/204877/
But when I finished following these instructions, I encountered this error when starting:
    java.lang.Exception: File \eclipse.exe does not exists.  Pass a correct -eclipsehome option
            at org.eclipse.help.internal.standalone.Eclipse.ensureEclipseExeExists(Eclipse.java:170)
            at org.eclipse.help.internal.standalone.Eclipse.prepareCommand(Eclipse.java:46)
            at org.eclipse.help.internal.standalone.Eclipse.run(Eclipse.java:88)

To start, I used the command:
java -classpath \eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.help.base-4.2.100.jar org.eclipse.help.standalone.Infocenter -command start -eclipse \eclipse -plugincustomization \eclipse\plugins\com.aviatron.help.mega\plugin_customization.ini -port 8082

I added -noexec to the end of my command and the error became:
java.lang.Exception: Plugins directory \plugins does not exists.  Pass a correct -eclipsehome option
        at org.eclipse.help.internal.standalone.Eclipse.getStartupJar(Eclipse.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.help.internal.standalone.Eclipse.prepareJavaCommand(Eclipse.java:76)
        at org.eclipse.help.internal.standalone.Eclipse.prepareCommand(Eclipse.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.help.internal.standalone.Eclipse.run(Eclipse.java:88)

For some reason the error says that the folder in which I run this command does not contain the plugins folder. In fact, it is not there, but in my command I specify eclipse\plugins. Why does the search for the plugins subdirectory occur when running, and not eclipse\plugins?
Please tell me what actions I should take?

Please follow carefully the Eclipse help documentation which explains how to host Eclipse help, so-called Information Center. By the way, you might be interested in the modernized help UI (see here in action: legacy vs. modernized UI).

how does this relate to my question?

The link @howlger gave you is the current instructions on running a help server (information center). Your link is to a 13 year old article which is probably well out of date. Before messing around trying to trim things get this working with a normal Eclipse. The "Platform Runtime Binary" download here is pretty small and should have everything you need (this download requires a separate Java)

@greg-449 I can't figure out from this documentation how to launch the info center with my help plugin and my documentation, by default it shows the Eclipse documentation

How did you install your help plugin? There are different ways to do this. For example, you can simply copy the help plugin into the dropins folder. Following the Eclipse documentation works fine for me. According to your question you did not set -eclipsehome (see the error message you got: Pass a correct -eclipsehome option). The Eclipse documentation tells that this is needed and how to do this.

I already realized that I have the wrong eclipsehome, I'm trying to explain to you that I need my help to run with a minimal eclipse build that I can then use on devices without eclipse and in products not created on eclipse. That's why I'm asking you how I can make a minimal eclipse build to run the help created by me.

As greg-449 already said, the Platform Runtime Binary from the download of the Eclipse project are small and enough to run an info center. If you want to build a minimal product, you have to include the features org.eclipse.help, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.extras.feature and if you want include Java then you can use a minimal stripped JRE from Eclipse JustJ: org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.minimal.stripped.

Thanks to both of you, I was able to figure it out.
